# How to write automated integrated tests when using JTA?

Tags: jta, testing, integrated

I want to write integration tests for the application I'm working on. It uses JTA (multiple resources) and runs inside an application server. What is the best way for writing an automated test for such a scenario? Using an standalone transaction manager like atomikos or somehow leveraging the app server api/tools for transaction handling?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a good plan, might be a bit complicated satisfying the environment required by all those resources.